# Redirect from/to www with nginx-ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a kubernetes cluster with nginx-ingress and I try to redirect http://test.domain.com to http://www.test.domaine.com with nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect annotation.

But it doesn't seem to work.

My ingress ressource :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.test.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app
          servicePort: 8080
  - host: test.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app
          servicePort: 8080
```

I have tried many configuration but I can't make it work. The nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect annotation have no effect!

Comment: Looks like you need to add another annotation ```nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet```
checkout these links:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/50962994/6885968 
https://www.informaticsmatters.com/blog/2020/06/03/redirecting-to-www.html

Comment: @DamienCarlier Does the above solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is a community wiki answer. Feel free to expand it.

In order to make it work you also need to use the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` [annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet). For example:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  if ($host = 'example.com' ) {
    rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
  }
```

As already mentioned by @apoorvakamath in the comments, you can refer to [this guide](https://www.informaticsmatters.com/blog/2020/06/03/redirecting-to-www.html) for a step by step detailed example:

> The snippet is the clever aspect fo the solution. It allows you to add
> dynamic configuration to the ingress controller. We use it to detect
> the use of the non-www form of the URL and then simply issue a
> re-write that is pushed out (and back via your domain) to the www
> form.

Answer (score 0):

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: webui-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: 'false'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN";
      more_set_headers "X-Xss-Protection: 0";
      more_set_headers "Referrer-Policy: use strict-origin-when-cross-origin";
      if ($host = 'test.domain.com' ) {
         return 301 https://www.test.domain.com ;
      }
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 10m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: sha1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: route
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - test.domain.com
      secretName: test-tls
    - hosts:
        - www.test.domain.com
      secretName: www-tls
  rules:
    - host: test.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: webui
                port:
                  number: 8022
    - host: www.test.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: webui
                port:
                  number: 8022
```

once the below annotation is added your domain will redirect to www

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN";
  more_set_headers "X-Xss-Protection: 0";
  more_set_headers "Referrer-Policy: use strict-origin-when-cross-origin";
  if ($host = 'test.domain.com' ) {
     return 301 https://www.test.domain.com ;
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).