# Kubernetes nginx ingress https problems

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have set up an on-premises Kubernetes 1 node cluster on Ubuntu
with `nginx-ingress` and `metalLB`

I have 2 problems:

- If I go to my site with https://www.example.com it works but it doesn't with https://example.com (bad certificate).
- I would like to redirect HTTP to HTTPs (HTTP://example.com not working).

I have no problems with other subdomains (subdomain.example.com)

Here is my `Ingress`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: clientweb-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: clientweb-service
                port: 
                  number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    - www.example.com
    secretName: ethernial-tls-secret
```

Comment: Hello, could you please tell what exactly you mean by `HTTP` -> `HTTP`  redirection? Have you meant to redirect the `example.com` to `www.example.com`? Also I'd reckon this post could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655450/nginx-k8s-ingress-forcing-www-and-https

Comment: http -> https there is a typo
if i go to HTTP://example.com It needs to redirect to https://example.com

Comment: However the www fix you suggested works!

Comment: Please verify your [Issuer](https://cert-manager.io/docs/concepts/issuer/) and the certificate that the `nginx-ingress` is sending. It could be that your `Ingress controller` is using a default "fake" one: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#default-ssl-certificate